# Get JavaScript variable into JSP

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

I am doing a point of sale web-app using MySql and JSP, and in the sales module i have given a autocomplete to get the itemcode from the table. and the form is [IMAGE HERE](http://postimage.org/image/5g6b4z315/).

The problem is i want the `Item Name` `Quantity` and the  `Unit Price` to appear in the respective text boxes.

What i tried is as below :

```
           function getData()
            {   
                var code=document.getElementById("itemCode");

            <%Sales dbObj = new Sales();
                ResultSet rs = dbObj.captureItemDetails(code);// javascript variable
                if (rs.next()) {
            %>
```

1. how can i get the desired javaScript variable in the JSP code ?
2. Is there any solution to overcome my problem which i am not aware of ?

Please help . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variable can not be accessed directly from jsp as javascript variable is at client side and jsp variables are server side variables.

There is a way to access it.

You can use hidden fields to do this as follow:
**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById("jsvar");
el.value = "jsvalue_value";
</script>
<form action="./JSPpage.jsp" >
<input id="jsvar" type="hidden" value="" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JSP**

```
<%
if (request.getParameter("jsvar") != null) { %>
 Javascript variable value: <%=request.getParameter("jsvar")%>
<%   
} 
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. In your above code you have given a form action, but sorry i dont have a form it is tables rows and it consists of textboxes. what i need is as soon as the item code is selected as in the [image](http://postimage.org/image/5g6b4z315/) i need the information to appear like on onBlur() for the `item Code`. how can i do this ?